# Meet-semilattice is a semilattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I want to show that a meet-semilattice (i.e. a poset such that any finite subset has a meet) is a semilattice as defined algebraically (binary operation with associativity, commutativity, idempotency).

For commutativity and idempotency it is obvious.
For associativity I want to use the fact that $\wedge \{ a,b,c \}$ exists and doesn't depend on how we take $a,b$ and $c$.

So my question is : is my last argument correct and sufficient ? Or is it wrong ?

Comment: How do you know that the meet of $a, b, c$ is equal to the meet of $a \land b$ and $c$? I think there is something to be explained here.

Comment: @ZhenLin I think $\wedge \{a,b,c\} = (a \wedge b) \wedge c$ because of the maximality property of the infimum

Comment: You seem to be on right path. Now it depends on the details.

Comment: Let $m_0 = a \wedge b$, by definition we have $m_0 \leq a, m_0 \leq b$ and that $m_0$ is the greatest that satisfy these inequalities. Then we have $m_0 \wedge c = m$, once again $m \leq m_0, m \leq c$ with $m$ the greatest. Thus $m$ is the greatest element such that $m\leq a, m\leq b, m\leq c$ i.e. the definition of $\wedge\{ a,b,c \}$. So at the end we have $(a \wedge b) \wedge c = \wedge\{ a,b,c \}$ and we can do the same for $a \wedge (b \wedge c)$. Is that correct ?